# Finding log file of ntp daemon in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, logs, startup, ntp

My Ubuntu is set to run `ntp` before `dovecot` at startup. (See my earlier question: [The rc0.d,rc1.d,... directories in /etc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/the-rc0-d-rc1-d-directories-in-etc-in-ubuntu-10-04-lts))

However, I suspect that `dovecot` may have finished executing before `ntp` finished (even if the `ntp` started executing earlier).

What logs should I look at to find out whether this was the case?

---

(In case you're interested: The reason for my suspicion is a message like this in `/var/log/mail.log` when I rebooted my machine (it had been a long time since the last reboot):

> dovecot: Fatal: Time just moved backwards by 43 seconds. This might cause a lot of problems, so I'll just kill myself now.

This was fixed by rebooting the machine again, providing further support for my suspicion.)

Comment: I'm inclined to think that your internet was lagging or not ready while booting, which made `ntp` updates the clock pretty late and caused `dovecot` to exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ntp` writes to the system log file (could be either `daemon.log` or `syslog.log`) any error or warning message. It could be changed in the configuration file `ntp.conf` using the `logfile /path/to/file.log` or the `-l` switch while starting.