# Why start script and kill script does not appear in pairs in rcX.d folder?

Tags: init-script

The scripts need to be executed at boot time was put in the **`/etc/init.d`**,and files contained in **`/etc/rc*.d`** was the symbolic links point to files in /etc/init.d.Furthermore the names of the symbolic links indicate whether the service is to be started (S*) or stopped (killed, K*) in specific runlevel.
I issue a command “ls -al” to inspect the files in the **`/etc/rc3.d`**,the output as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Apr  6 23:04 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4096 May 22  2015 ..
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   20 May 22  2015 K50netconsole -> ../init.d/netconsole
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   17 May 22  2015 K90network -> ../init.d/network
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   17 May 22  2015 S00livesys -> ../init.d/livesys
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   16 Apr  6 23:04 S85mongod -> ../init.d/mongod
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   15 May 31  2015 S95jexec -> ../init.d/jexec
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   22 May 22  2015 S99livesys-late -> ../init.d/livesys-late
```

I supposes that start script and kill script should appear in pairs, but it`s wrong,why?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for RHEL6 or similar breed of Linux, these scripts are generally managed by `chkconfig(8)` , which makes sure there is EITHER a start script or a stop script for each runlevel, for each service, not that they are made in pairs. (Not sure about Ubuntu or others).

From man page for `chkconfig`:

> ```
> Note that for every service, each runlevel has either a start script 
> or a stop script.  When switching runlevels, init will not re-start an 
> already-started service, and will not re-stop a  service that is not running.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> --add name
>   This option adds a new service for management by chkconfig.  When a new service is added, 
>   chkconfig ensures that the service has either a start or a kill entry in  every  runlevel.  
>   If  any  runlevel is missing such an entry, chkconfig creates the 
>   appropriate entry as specified by the default values in the init script.
> ```

An answer to [another question about runlevels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83748/the-rc0-d-rc1-d-directories-in-etc#83753) describes the naming convention.

> Now, the naming scheme is also quite simple. Scripts whose name begins with an S will be started at the runlevel in question while those whose name begins with K will be killed.

If you look at the runlevel change script `/etc/rc`, you can see how whenever the runlevel is being changed the `S*` are executed with `start` input parameter, AFTER the `K*` scripts are executed with the `stop` parameter.
Having both K and S scripts would mean the script is stopped and started in each run level.

```
# rc            This file is responsible for starting/stopping
#               services when the runlevel changes.
...
# First, run the KILL scripts.
for i in /etc/rc$runlevel.d/K* ; do
        ...
        $i stop
done
# Now run the START scripts.
for i in /etc/rc$runlevel.d/S* ; do
        ...
                exec $i start
        ...
done
```

I am only looking at RHEL6 machine, so if someone can confirm how other distros differ, please do.